# How to resolve Backdrop bug on Angular Material Bottom Sheet?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am facing an error while using *Angular Material Bottom Sheet* at a very specific use case. This error can be witnessed on https://material.angular.io as well.

You can Reproduce the error as follows.

- **Step 1** on go to https://material.angular.io/components/categories
- **Step 2** Head over to ***Bottom Sheet*** under **Popups & Modals** .
- **Step 3** Click on **Open file** button. *[This will open a bottom sheet]*
- **Step 4** Click back button on your browser. *[I use chrome]*
- **Step 5** Again Head over to ***Bottom Sheet*** under **Popups & Modals** .
- **Step 6** Again Click on **Open file** button. *[This will **not** open a bottom sheet]*

**Error:** This will produce a backdrop to cover the screen.

> **My use case:** I am using this in a mobile PWA with disabled backdrop close. This gives my App a dead end. :(.
>
> Please let me know if there is a way out or I might end up re-coding the whole feature. Thanks in advance.

***Bug Recording:*** [Click to view video of bug reproduction.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MlhR03RBSnee-ULv0CnrIu4IZnLY49oj/view)

*Left side of the Screenshot is bug and right side is what it should be like.*
[image]

Comment: can't replicate the issue on mobile chrome

Comment: @lan P.: I just Replicated it on my Pixel Device with the latest chrome installed. I can share a recording if  that can help?

Comment: yes, i think it would help by adding a screenshot ofthat issue

Comment: @lan P.: As per your suggestion I have added both Screenshot and Video Recording. I hope this will give you a clearer picture of the situation. Thanks.

Comment: yeah I just replicated it by quickly pressing the back button.. thanks for screenshot, I will investigate further